# Why does my map plot remain the same size (and not resize accordingly) when I expand the plot?

Tags: r, resize, maps

I have plotted two sets of points on a world map in RStudio using `maps`, and when I try to maximise the plot, the map remains the same size.

I feel that I am missing something.

In Rstudio:

[image]

Expanded plot:

[image]

I would like the world map to maximise to fit my screen in order to better-distribute the points but it remains the same size.

Where am I going wrong?

Or is there a better package to do this in?

**My code:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)
library(geosphere)

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
map('world')

points(x = geochats$origin_lon, y = geochats$origin_lat, col = "green", cex = 1, pch = 20)
points(x = geochats$end_lon, y = geochats$end_lat, col = "red", cex = 1, pch = 20)
```

Comment: This is an issue with RStudio that I've run into as well. Try saving your plot to a PNG, and viewing it outside of RStudio.

Comment: I just tried that but it is still very low quality/size.  Is there another package that perhaps renders/resizes maps correctly?

Comment: Have you tried using the dpi argument in png()? Set dpi =3200 or something high to increase resolution.

Answer (score 0):

`map()` uses a rather archaic method to fix the plot window and aspect ratio. It doesn't behave well after rescaling the plot window (also outside of Rstudio). Not sure about Rstudio, but I suppose you can avoid this problem by using a standard plot command:

```
mymap <- map("world", plot=FALSE)
plot(mymap,asp=1,type="l",frame=0,axes=0,xlab="",ylab="")
```